# Two missing positional arguments error

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I'm learning to program interfaces and I'm facing the following problem:

```
soma() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'.
```

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me resolve this issue. I've provided my code below:

```
from tkinter import*

class calculadora:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.somar = Button(root,text = 'SOMAR',command = self.soma)
        self.somar.pack(side=TOP)
        entry1 = Entry(frame)
        entry1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        entry2 = Entry(frame)
        entry2.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        labelR=Label(frame,text='[Aqui]').pack(side=TOP)

    def soma(self,a,b):
        self.a = int(entry1.get())
        self.b = int(entry2.get())
        labelR['text'] = self.a+self.b



root = Tk()
root.title("Calculadora")
root.geometry("300x300+200+200")
x =calculadora(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just remove the `a` and `b` arguments from `soma()`, you are not using them in the function. They are entirely not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.somar = Button(root,text = 'SOMAR',command = self.soma)
```

That line defines that every time your button is clicked, it will call `self.soma` meaning it will call the `soma` method with the object as a first argument.

However, your `soma` method needs three arguments: `self`, `a` and `b`. These are missing for the moment.

Edit:

If you want to solve these problems, either include them in your command

```
self.somar = Button(root,text = 'SOMAR',command = lambda: self.soma(True, False)
```

Here you will call your soma method with a = True and b= False

Or you could also remove the a and b argument in soma, they're actually useless for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your `Calculadora` class (class names are usually capitalized)

1. you use `entry1` and `entry2` in your `soma` function, but they are not defined outside the `__init__` method so you need to change them to `self.entry1/2` to be able to access them from the `soma` function.
2. The same is true for `labelR`, but also since `Label(frame,text='[Aqui]').pack(side=TOP)` returns `None`, `labelR` is `None`. You need to separate the label creation from the packing.
3. For the `soma` function, `a` and `b` are useless arguments that should be removed and I removed the `self` in front of `a` and `b` in

   ```
   self.a = int(entry1.get())
   self.b = int(entry2.get())
   ```

   because they are not necessary here.

Here is the code:

```
class Calculadora:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.somar = Button(root,text = 'SOMAR',command = self.soma)
        self.somar.pack(side=TOP)
        self.entry1 = Entry(frame) # 1
        self.entry1.pack(side=BOTTOM) 
        self.entry2 = Entry(frame) # 1
        self.entry2.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.labelR = Label(frame,text='[Aqui]') # 2
        self.labelR.pack(side=TOP) # 2

    def soma(self): # 3
        a = int(self.entry1.get())
        b = int(self.entry2.get())
        self.labelR['text'] = a + b
```